# How to solve net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) for leaflet.css and leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, leaflet

I have created a project which is working fine when I open it with VSCode live server (127.0.0.1:5501/index.html).
[image]

The following is the image of the scripts in the index.html, and the files path.
[image]

The css file for leaflet.css located in the head of index.html looks like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/leaflet/leaflet.css">`

I'm currently using XAMPP to run my app and the project is located in the htdocs.
Whenever I run the code with XAMPP, I get the following:
[image]

So, the map is not showing.
The errors show up:

GET http://localhost/project1/vendors/leaflet/leaflet.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

GET http://localhost/project1/vendors/leaflet/leaflet.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you can inspect the source code on browser. Here is the complete project: https://stephenorowole.co.uk/project1/

Comment: I just had to make sure I specified the path correctly.